# Could not create Java Virtual Machine due to unrecognised option -p

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm trying to make my first Minecraft mod. All I'm adding is a simple gavel. However, after I build the gradle project and run the runClient, It fails to start the Java Virtual Machine.

Command:

`"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\bin\java.exe" -Dforge.logging.console.level=debug -Dforge.logging.markers=REGISTRIES -DlegacyClassPath.file=C:\Users\broth\Documents\Gavel\build\classpath\runClient_minecraftClasspath.txt -DignoreList=bootstraplauncher,securejarhandler,asm-commons,asm-util,asm-analysis,asm-tree,asm,client-extra,fmlcore,javafmllanguage,mclanguage,forge- -DnativesDirectory=C:\Users\broth\Documents\Gavel\build\natives -DmergeModules=jna-5.8.0.jar,jna-platform-58.0.jar,java-objc-bridge-1.0.0.jar -p C:\Users\broth\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\cpw.mods\bootstraplauncher\1.0.0\f55ddbb35612c6745cefc47d1a0d6dbfb25d3982\bootstraplauncher-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\broth\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\cpw.mods\securejarhandler\1.0.1\cefd70d447a84ea4949fda0ee654f9a95f72d4da\securejarhandler-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\broth\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.ow2.asm\asm-commons\9.2\f4d7f0fc9054386f2893b602454d48e07d4fbead\asm-commons-9.2.jar;C:\Users\broth\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.ow2.asm\asm-util\9.2\fbc178fc5ba3dab50fd7e8a5317b8b647c8e8946\asm-util-9.2.jar;C:\Users\broth\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.ow2.asm\asm-analysis\9.2\7487dd756daf96cab9986e44b9d7bcb796a61c10\asm-analysis-9.2.jar;C:\Users\broth\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.ow2.asm\asm-tree\9.2\d96c99a30f5e1a19b0e609dbb19a44d8518ac01e\asm-tree-9.2.jar;C:\Users\broth\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.ow2.asm\asm\9.2\81a03f76019c67362299c40e0ba13405f5467bff\asm-9.2.jar --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH --add-opens java.base/java.util.jar=cpw.mods.securejarhandler --add-exports java.base/sun.security.util=cpw.mods.securejarhandler --add-exports jdk.naming.dns/com.sun.jndi.dns=java.naming -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump "-Dos.name=Windows 10" -Dos.version=10.0 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=30381:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "<lots of files>" cpw.mods.bootstraplauncher.BootstrapLauncher --launchTarget forgeclientuserdev --version MOD_DEV --assetIndex 1.18 --assetsDir C:\Users\broth\.gradle\caches\forge_gradle\assets --gameDir . --fml.forgeVersion 39.0.66 --fml.mcVersion 1.18.1 --fml.forgeGroup net.minecraftforge --fml.mcpVersion 20211210.034407`

I'm using IntelliJ Idea to build this, I've updated the run configs, and I can't seem to find anything to help me anywhere. I'm unfamiliar with options, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What JDK is in use (File | Project Structure)? Try using 11 or 17 version. Please also show your run config.

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov JDK 8, as that is what works with Minecraft. I have no clue how to show my run config since I cannot upload a photo.